# What is wrong with the below codes?

Tags: sql, syntax

```
insert into ageData (PatientID, Age) 
select PatientID from AEDepartment, 
select DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,GETDATE())/8766 from AEDepartment;
```

Error Message:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword select
```

Answer (score 4):

you should have only one `SELECT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO ageData (PatientID, Age) 
SELECT PatientID, DATEDIFF(hour,DOB,GETDATE())/8766 
FROM   AEDepartment
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the white check mark (*around 15mins to an hour later*). This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)